# Array sorts wrong when moving first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am encountering a curious error in the creation of my array. I try to save a sort order of fields when the item is dragged, and this goes good for most of the part. If i grab an item, i save the field order in which they are in my fieldlist, which i push into an array.

This goes well for all fields, except always for the first one. If i move the first item 1 spot down, it will in the array be moved to the last position and not to the 2nd position and I cant wrap my head arround it why it does this behavior. If i move an item to the first spot, it will also bork that by keeping it in the same position, if i drag something else, it will in the end move to that position.

[image: correct array]

This is its start position, the array result equals to `Array(6) [ 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10 ]`, however, if i drag the articlenumber field down 1 spot, my array is getting borked.

[image: borked array]

The array becomes now `Array(6) [ 2, 5, 8, 10, 9, 1 ]` rather than `Array(6) [ 2, 1, 5, 8, 10, 9 ]`

Is my logic wrong?

Each draggable item is made up as following in PHP

```
echo '<div class="panel panel-default draggable" data-fieldid="'.$instance['fieldid'].'">';
      <-- not interesting code -->
echo '</div>';
```

And this is my javascript which is in JQuery

```
$('body').on('dragstop', '.draggable', function(e) {
    var arr = [];
    $('.draggable').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (typeof $(this).data('fieldid') != 'undefined') {
            arr.push($this.data('fieldid'));
        }       
    })      
    console.log(arr);       

    var vars = {    
        url : domain + '/core/ajax/profile.php',
        form: 'fieldorder', 
        profileid : $(this).attr('data-value'), 
        order: arr      
    };
    datahandle(vars);

});
```

Does anybody see where it goes wrong?

== edit ==

a little more debugging gave me more insight, since this actually happens in the end everywhere, its like its not registering everything correct. I thought it did, but all items when moved are down a notch occasionally. I put a timeout on it to see if it was a registering thing in the DOM, but no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The earlier added `setTimeout()` functionality was actually the key, however my timer was too short to actually have the DOM registering everything correctly. I had it set to half a second, which is appearantly to slow. If I set it to 1 second. It actually goes correct, odd.

```
$('body').on('dragstop', '.draggable', function(e) {
    var arr = [];
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.draggable').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if (typeof $(this).data('fieldid') != 'undefined') {
                arr.push($this.data('fieldid'));
            }
        })

        var vars = {    
            url : domain + '/core/ajax/profile.php',
            form: 'fieldorder', 
            profileid : $(this).attr('data-value'), 
            order: arr      
        };

        datahandle(vars);
        console.log(arr);

    }, 1000);     
});
```

Comment: Go ahead and mark this as solved if you're satisfied with  your solution

Comment: I am, but due to StackOverflow rules, can do it after 2 days as it is my own answer tp my own question @Kinglish